# ontouchstart not working on Windows 8 Tablet

Tags: javascript, windows, touch, tablet, ontouchstart

I'm trying to get ontouchstart working for windows tablet. If detected it disables the top layer of my links so that a click event allows the menu to remain open (instead of a hover effect).

The following code is working on other touch devices so I'm not sure if there is anything else I need to do?

```
 $topLink.on('click', function (e) {

        $dropDown.removeClass('child');
        $dropDown.not($(this).next('.dropdown')).removeClass('open');
        $topLink.not($(this)).removeClass('active-link');

        $(this).next('.dropdown').toggleClass('open');
        $(this).toggleClass('active-link');

        if (("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement) || ($window.width() < 1120)) {
            // disable top level links for touch
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE/Edge has no `TouchEvents` (at least not enabled by default), it has `PointerEvents`.

Have a look at caniuse.com:
[PointerEvents](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer)
[TouchEvents](https://caniuse.com/#feat=touch)